# how to get route name from current url in angular 7

Tags: angular, angular-routing

i have multiple component in routing when i start routing it,s work fine but i have some conditions to implment with this routing is their a way to get route name from url 
this is my routing

```
const routes: Routes = [
{path:'',redirectTo:'home',pathMatch:'full'},
{path:'home',component:HomeComponent},
{path:'about',component:AboutComponent},
{path:'portfolio',component:PorfolioComponent},
{path:'blog',component:BlogComponent},
{path:'contact',component:ContactComponent},
{path:'web-development',component:WebDelopementComponent},
{path:'software-app',component:SoftwareAppComponent},
{path:'graphic-designing',component:GraphicDesigningComponent},
{path:'e-business',component:ECommerceComponent},
{path:'single-blog/:id',component:SingleBlogComponent},
{path:'service-detail/:id',component:ServiceDetailComponent},
{path:'**',redirectTo:'home',pathMatch:'full'},
];
```

for example this is my url

```
 http://localhost:4200/home or http://localhost:4200/about
```

i wan to get home or about from this url's so how can i do that in angular 7

Comment: read the document
https://angular.io/api/router/Router#url
https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRouteSnapshot#url
https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute#url

Comment: Unclear. Routes don't even have a name BTW. And it seems you have already chosen a solution to solve the problem, but without exposing the problem. So what is the concrete problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: hy dear i just want to pick hom about blog from url

Answer (score 2):

Here is code :

```js
     constructor(private _router: Router,private activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute) {
           console.log(activatedRoute.snapshot.url); // array of states
           console.log(activatedRoute.snapshot.url[0].path);
           //this will give the path name
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

perhaps it will be useful, the path outside the angular router context, but in your case better to use ActivatedRoute or Router

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';


constructor(private location: Location) {
  console.log(location.path());
}
```

Comment: it,s not working when i start routing it,s always give me the home route not others when clicked